# Angular 4 error formating Date field in ISO format with DatePipe

Tags: html, node.js, angular, date

In an angular 4 / nodejs application, I am retrieving the following date field from MongoDB:

- "2018-06-14T03:00:00.000Z"

Here is my HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="this.Lacador.dataAssociacao">
   <p style="margin-top: 10px" type="text"> <label style="font-weight: normal"> {{  this.Lacador.dataAssociacao | date:"dd/MM/yyyy" }} </label></p>
</div>
```

In the screen, the date is displayed (as per image), but I have an error in the console which messes with all the scripts of the page:

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'function Date() { [native code] }' for pipe 'DatePipe'
at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.es5.js:2610)
at DatePipe.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.DatePipe.transform (common.es5.js:3506)
at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (core.es5.js:11665)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12370)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12303)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13167)
at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.es5.js:13146)
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (LacadoresViewComponent.html:96)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:13131)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12275)
```

Date displayed correctly:

[image: Date with format]

Any clues on why it throws an exception, even through it formats the field as I want?

Edit: Added a missing quote.

Comment: You're missing a closing quote. `date:"dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: Sorry, was a type, the quote is in my code, and the problem persists. 
But thanks for the input :)

Comment: no errors here... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qshduj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts Could you try and reproduce with your actual code?